# java.net.BindException even though I'm properly closing my sockets

Tags: java, sockets, io

I am currently trying to create a program that tests communication speeds between TCP and UDP. However, I've run into an issue. When the clientside `connectTCP` method is called on the second trial, it crashes with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:513)
    at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:661)
    at me.gabriel.sciencefair.TestClient.connectTCP(TestClient.java:30)
    at me.gabriel.sciencefair.ClientController.main(ClientController.java:9)
```

I'm not sure why this happens. I may be calling the `connectTCP` method over and over again, but I'm disconnecting the socket properly, and that should be enough for the socket to unbind, right? Moreover, the server side, the program works fine, and waits patiently for the client to connect for another trial (not gonna happen).

---

At first, I was getting this error on UDP because (quite logically) I was using the same address/port for both client and server. I fixed this by adding two constants on the server and client end called `MY_IP` and `MY_PORT`. For both of these, `MY_IP` is `localhost` and `MY_PORT` is  `12344` and `12345` for client and server respectively. Both bind to their IPs and PORTs, and connect to the ip and port specified in the parameters of the `connectTCP()` and `startTCP()` (client and server, respectively) methods. I run those methods over and over again, for however many trials I need in my experiment. An error is thrown clientside on the second trial.

My code can be viewed at https://github.com/Archonic944/ProtocolSpeedTest.

Comment: By the way, you need to post code here to get it looked at; no-one likes off-site code.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing a bind on the client side. There's no need. The common pattern for TCP is that the server binds to a particular port, but the client just lets the stack pick a free 'ephemeral' port.

(The client does not need to bind to an interface either).

You're probably falling foul of the requirement that a port be unusable for a time after disconnection (see [TIME_WAIT](https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states) state in the [TCP state diagram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg). Using an ephemeral port avoids that, by getting you a different port number each time.

If you run 'netstat' in a terminal window immediately after running the client once, you'll see TIME_WAIT state.